# JQuery/Ajax and when/done/promise confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, .when

I am trying to accomplish the following:
1) Get data some source and "do something with it".
2) Get data some other source and "do something with it".
3) The datafetching should preferrably run asynchronous (at the same time ie. the second one should not wait for the first one to complete).
4) When both are completed, some business logic runs - but ONLY when they are completed.

I have created a small JSFiddle to show how I thought this could work - but unfortunately it does not:
a) The datafetching calls are executed sequentially.
b) The business logic from step 4 above executes before the datafetching has even begun...

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/LeifFrederiksen/emttmhm7/

```
$.when(
    getOneThing(),
    getAnotherThing()
).done(
    function() {
        console.log("Got it all");
        $("#Output").append("<BR>Got it all");
    }
);

function getOneThing() {
   commonFunctionToGetStuff("oneKindOfThings",renderOneKindOfThings);
}

function getAnotherThing() {
   commonFunctionToGetStuff("anotherKindOfThings",renderAnotherKindOfThings);
}

function commonFunctionToGetStuff (listTitle,successFunction) {
    var url = "https://httpbin.org/get";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log("Calling renderfunction for " + listTitle);
        $("#Output").append("<BR>Calling renderfunction for " + listTitle);
        successFunction(data);
        console.log("Back from renderfunction for " + listTitle);
        $("#Output").append("<BR>Back from renderfunction for " + listTitle);
    });
}

function renderOneKindOfThings(data) {
    // Do something with the data...
    console.log("Doing oneKindOfThings.");
    $("#Output").append("<BR>Doing oneKindOfThings.");
}

function renderAnotherKindOfThings(data) {
    // Do something with the data...
    console.log("Doing anotherKindOfThings.");
    $("#Output").append("<BR>Doing anotherKindOfThings.");
}
```

Any help clearing up how the structure should be is highly appreciated.

I need to maintain the structure where the function that performs the actual Ajax call is kind of generic, and can be called by simple wrapper functions with parameters controlling what datasource to use - like it is in the example :-)

Regards
Leif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from your `commonFunctionToGetStuff`-method and the methods that call it. Otherwise, you're passing in `undefined` into your `when`-function which will immediately execute the done-callback. Also you have a few erroneous callback names (it's `done` or `then`, not `success`).

```
function getOneThing() {
   return commonFunctionToGetStuff("oneKindOfThings",renderOneKindOfThings);
}

function getAnotherThing() {
   return commonFunctionToGetStuff("anotherKindOfThings",renderAnotherKindOfThings);
}

function commonFunctionToGetStuff (listTitle,successFunction) {
    var url = "https://httpbin.org/get";

    return $.ajax({...})
            .then(function (data) { ...});
}
```

Comment: Hi Kenneth,

Thanks a lot for your help - it works like a dream now :-)

Regards
Leif